# change the location of zoom buttons (+-) in Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to change the location of `Zoom button controls (+)(-)` on the `map` in `Xamarin.Forms`. Is it Possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without implementing your own Map control using Custom Renderers

Comment: Are you saying that you want to relocate the default zoom control of google map for android platform?

Comment: yes,you are right `Grace` I want to relocate the default zoom control of `google map` for android platform but in `xamarin.forms.maps`

Comment: @user3367428, sorry for the late response, I didn't receive any notification about your response, I'm not sure whether the default zoom control can be moved or not, but a custom zoom control would solve your issue, would that help?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I think there is no method to relocate the default zoom control of google map, but as we said, you can use custom renderer to create your own map control, so you can customize your zoom control, for example:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:MapWithMyZoomControl x:Name="map"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Text="Zoom In" Clicked="Zoom_In" />
        <Button Text="Zoom Out" Clicked="Zoom_Out" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

MapWithMyZoomControl :

```
public class MapWithMyZoomControl : Map
{
    public ZoomState MyZoom
    {
        get { return (ZoomState)GetValue(MyZoomProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyZoomProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MyZoomProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "MyZoom",
            returnType: typeof(ZoomState),
            declaringType: typeof(MapWithMyZoomControl),
            defaultValue: ZoomState.normal,
            propertyChanged: OnZoomPropertyChanged);

    public static void OnZoomPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
    }

    public enum ZoomState
    {
        normal,
        zoomin,
        zoomout
    }
}
```

Renderer:

```
public class MapWithMyZoomControlRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap map;

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;

        map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (MapWithMyZoomControl)e.NewElement;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        var element = Element as MapWithMyZoomControl;
        if (e.PropertyName == "MyZoom" && map != null)
        {
            if (element.MyZoom == MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.zoomin)
            {
                map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomIn());
            }
            else if (element.MyZoom == MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.zoomout)
            {
                map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomOut());
            }
            element.MyZoom = MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add assembly in renderer like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MapWithMyZoomControl), typeof(MapWithMyZoomControlRenderer))]
```

Now you can change the button styles and locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace WD.EMP.APP.Droid.Renderer {
    public class GEMapRenderer: MapRenderer {
        protected override void OnMapReady(Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap googleMap) {
            base.OnMapReady(googleMap);
            NativeMap.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 500);
        }
    }
}

NativeMap.SetPadding(0,0,0,500 );
```

by setting padding google map will solve your problem, place `NativeMap.SetPadding(0,0,0,500 );` in renderer file in `onmapready` function

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the elegant answer. NativeMap.SetPadding worked perfectly on Xamarin.Android - Thanks!

Comment: This is a very dirty solution, and also, it won't let you change the position of other elements, like "My Location" control.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the padding property.

```
<maps:Map
    Padding="0, 0, 0, 20">
```